# controlling lauterbach through command line

Tags: embedded, real-time, lauterbach

I have condition that i have to flash multiple output files one by one to the mpc controller. We use GUI for lauterbach to do the flashing and running software.  Now i want to do the same via >command line argument. Some one please explain me what all things are needed for controlling the lauterbach through command prompt.

I want to use Lauterbach Powerdebug interface/ usb2 for the debugging purpose.

Comment: Lauterbach are a company not a specific product.  You should specify exactly what hardware and software products you are using.

Comment: i have updated the interface thank you for notification.

Answer (score 3):

You can remote-control trace32 via a UDP port using the t32rem command.
t32rem is typically installed in C:\T32\bin\windows64\

Your t32 configuration file (config.t32) must have "RCL=NETASSIST" in it.
And you need to enable the API port, either via the t32start options or in your custom xxx.ts2 (configuration file).

Out of the box you should then be able to run any t32 command.  E.g.:

C:\T32\bin\windows64\t32rem.exe localhost port=20000 data.dump 100000

Replace "data.dump 100000" with anything T32 understands, e.g. "do pgm_my_flash.cmm"

Comment: Acually i am using GUI for this trace32 interface. anyway these information looks helpful

Comment: Yes, you can remote control the command line in the GUI exactly in the way I described.

Comment: What would the custom file, xxx.ts2 would look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use telnet to remote control the debugger. NETASSIST must be set.