# controlling trace32 via command line

Tags: real-time, lauterbach

I have to flash single output files one by one to mpc controller, instead of using the GUI i am trying to do it automatically via command prompt, i have searched and i found this link 
[controlling lauterbach through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895207/controlling-lauterbach-through-command-line)
i tried to use the demo in C:\T32\demo\api\capi\test\t32rem.exe like the answer says but i can not find the t32rem.exe specified in the answer 
Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 7):

t32rem.exe should be located at C:\T32\bin\windows\t32rem.exe

However for your goal of programming a flash without the GUI, I would recommend to use a PRACTICE script (*.cmm file) instead of using the remote API. Pass your PRACTICE script to your TRACE32 executable on start with `-s <file>`

E.g.

```
C:\T32\bin\windows\t32mppc.exe -s C:\T32\myFlashScript.cmm
```

In your script use the `FLASH` commands and close TRACE32 with `QUIT <returncode>`

Comment: I am trying to automate some stuff. I tried using the command you put forward in this example, but it did not work. It just opened up the program but script didn't run. Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: If you have a very old version of TRACE32 it might not yet support the -s option. Use instead the syntax `C:\T32\bin\windows\t32mppc.exe -c C:\T32\config.t32, C:\T32\myFlashScript.cmm` (note the mandatory comma) and of course be sure that you have all three files.

Comment: Hi Rohit, from what you are writing I can't see what you are doing exactly. In general it does work. If you are facing problems anyway, I suggest to contact either the Lauterbach support or to open a new question here on Stackoverflow describing what you try to achieve and what you've done so far.

Comment: Hi @Holger, I was successful in running the .cmm file using command-line, but now am stuck in another problem. Please help me with "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670193/error-in-running-trace32-with-command-line". Please note that the program I am running is not t32mppc.exe. I hope my question makes sense there.